# GUI is not appearing on desktop

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run the program the GUI is not appearing on the desktop

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

label1 = Label(root, text="Bench")
label2 = Label(root, text="Deadlift")
label3 = Label(root, text="Squat")
label1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
label2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
label3.grid(row=2, sticky=E)
e1 = Entry(root)
e2 = Entry(root)
e3 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
l2 = Label(root)


def callback():
    total = sum(int(e.get()) for e in (e1, e2, e3))
    l2.config(text="answer = %s" % total)


b1 = Button(root, text="enter", command=callback)
b1.pack()
l2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I expected the GUI to appear. any answer is greatly appreciated I am a beginner and trying to figure this out.

Comment: How exactly did you execute this code? Did you get any python error messages?

Comment: You used `.grid()` on most of your widgets, but `.pack()` for `b1` and `l2`.  The result of conflicting geometry managers in the same parent widget is an infinite loop, so your program never entered its mainloop.

Answer (score 1):

When you use .pack and .grid a conflict it occurred. you just to change the .pack for .grid and fix the def Label, .config isn't a valid argument for labels, so put his inside the function solve the problem.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

label1 = Label(root, text="Bench")
label2 = Label(root, text="Deadlift")
label3 = Label(root, text="Squat")
label1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
label2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
label3.grid(row=2, sticky=E)


e1 = Entry(root)
e2 = Entry(root)
e3 = Entry(root)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)


def callback():
    total = sum(int(e.get()) for e in (e1, e2, e3))
    Label(root, text="answer = %s" % total).grid(row=3, column=1)


b1 = Button(root, text="enter", command=callback).grid(row=3)


root.mainloop()
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: `.config(...)` is a valid function to modify widget attributes and it is more appropriate than recreate new label whenever the button is clicked.  Moreover, `b1` is None as it is assigned the result of `grid(...)`.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know this. Thanks, knowledge is always welcome.